# Is the Lower and Upper Bounds of Roots Theorem Applicable to All Polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider the polynomial:

$$P(x)=x^3-4x^2-17x+60=(x+4)(x-3)(x-5)$$

This implies that $5$ is the upper bound and $-4$ is the lower bound, however, if $P(x)$ is divided by $x-5$ through synthetic division, it does have a negative entry.

$$\frac{x^3-4x^2-17x+60}{x-5}=x^2+x-12$$

Am I missing something?

The theorem states that for real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, a root $a$ is a lower bound and $b$ is an upper bound for the roots of a polynomial if every other real root $c$ satisfies $a<c<b$.

1. If a polynomial is divided by $x-a$ such that $a<0$ using synthetic division, and the the row that contains the quotient has entries that are alternately non-positive and non-negative, then a is a lower bound for the real roots. A zero in the entries may be consider positive or negative depending on the needs.
2. If a polynomial is divided by $x-b$ such that $b>0$ using synthetic division, and the row that contains the quotient has no negative entry, then $b$ is an upper bound for the real roots.

The roots of the polynomial $P$
$$P(x)=x^3-4x^2-17x+60$$
are $-4$, $3$, and $5$. In this case, $-4$ is the lower bound and $5$ is the upper bound.
Since $-4$ is a lower bound,
$$\frac{x^3-4x^2-17x+60}{x+4}=x^2-8x+15$$
The algebraic signs of $x^2-8x+15$ are positive-negative-positive, by the theorem, it must be a lower bound.
But for the upper bound $5$, the entries must all be non-negative, but $x^2+x-12$ is not. This is where I got confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Upper/lower bounds of what?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am referring to the upper and lower bounds of roots theorem

Comment: Can you state that theorem and spell out your confusion?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).